# fscanf for stdin not prompting for input

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fgets, scanf

Given below is a snippet from my code. I learned its better to use `fscanf` instead of `scanf`. But fscanf is not waiting for an input

```
switch (argc) {
            case 2: printf("\nEnter the subject code: ");
                while(fgets(temp_op->subject, BUF_NOTES, stdin)==NULL);
            case 3: printf("\nEnter the topic: ");
                while(fgets(temp_op->topic, BUF_TOPIC, stdin)==NULL);
            case 4: printf("\nEnter the Level: ");
                flag = fscanf(stdin,"%d",&temp_op->level);
            case 5: printf("\nEnter the Answer Key: ");
                while(fgets(temp_op->key, BUF_KEY, stdin)==NULL);
            case 6: printf("\nEnter any additional notes(optional): ");
                while(fgets(temp_op->notes, BUF_NOTES, stdin)==NULL);
                break;
            default:printf("\nExcess Arguments");
        }
```

The problem is for `case 5`. fgets is not waiting for an input, but case 6 doing good.

However, if I comment out the `case 4` line "flag =...", then the next fgets will prompt for input. Wierd. I wonder why is a previous fscanf affecting the latter fgets. My structure definition is:

```
typedef struct {
int mode ;
int level;
char subject[BUF_SUBJECT], topic[BUF_TOPIC], notes[BUF_NOTES], key[BUF_KEY];
} operation;
```

The full source is at http://pastebin.com/HVvGC3B7

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Does `fscanf` leave the newline character in the buffer?

Comment: Try `fflush()` to force the output buffer to emit, which usually happens on `\n`.

Comment: Btw you are forgetting `break;` in switch

Comment: `fscanf()` probably didn't consume all the input, so `fgets()` found some buffered characters and didn't need to wait for additional input from the user.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan  I think OP is intentionally omitting the `break`.  In my coding handbook, anytime a `case` "drops through` to the next line of code (that is no `break`), a _specific_ comment must be included.  Maybe as simple as `// drop through`.

Comment: @chux may be you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` - best to avoid.

`fscanf(stdin,"%d",...` leaves the `\n` in the input queue, that the following `fgets()` consumes without waiting for additional input.

Recommend use `fgets()` thoguhout and use `sscanf(buffer, "%d", ...` to get your integer.

Comment: @Jay Aurabind BTW: Looks like an infinite loop `while(fgets(..., ..., stdin)==NULL)` should you get an EOF or I/O error.

Comment: but what should I put in place of `buffer` when I need to take in from stdin using sscanf? stdin produces warnings, and doesnt work either, since buffer is supposed to be a `const char *` as mentioned in the manual. Only `getchar()` seem to work

Comment: Regaring the infinite loop, its the otherway round! :P I'm getting loop if I dont put NULL there :)

Comment: @Jay Aurabind, One does not use `sscanf()` directly to read from `stdin`.  Read into buffer and than scan buffer: `char buffer[sizeof(int)*3+3]; if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) handle_EOR_or_error_IO(); if (1 != sscanf(buffer, "%d", &temp_op->level) handle_format_error();`

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of `const` in `sscanf(const char *,`.  The buffer parameter supplied to `sscanf()` may be type `char *` or `const char *`.  The `const` implies `sscanf()` will not attempt to change the data pointer to by `buffer`.  It is not that a `const char *` _must_ be supplied to `sscanf()`.

Comment: Regarding the infinite loop, there is something else going on the is casuing an `infinite loop` you see.  `while(fgets(temp_op->key, BUF_KEY, stdin)!=NULL)` will _not_ cause an infinite loop.  NEither is `while(fgets(temp_op->key, BUF_KEY, stdin)==NULL)` what you want.  Certainly you want something like `if (fgets(temp_op->key, BUF_KEY, stdin)==NULL) handle_EOF();`.

Answer (score 2):

```
             case 4: printf("\nEnter the Level: ");
                flag = fscanf(stdin,"%d",&temp_op->level);
                //Here Return key left in buffer
             case 5: printf("\nEnter the Answer Key: ");
                while(fgets(temp_op->key, BUF_KEY, stdin)==NULL); // escapes because of newline
```

To avoid  simply add `getchar();` before `case 5` .

or as chux suggested you can also use `sscanf()`